# Horizontal Margins going outside of parent div in flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm getting some unexpected behavior with my margins using flex and I would like some help in understanding why.

I'v got some simple html like so:

```
<div className="dashboard">
    <div className="dashboard__inner-container">Inner Container</div>
</div>
```

And my scss file looks like this:

```
.dashboard {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #f4f6f8;
}

.dashboard__inner-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px 50px;
}
```

What I am expecting is that the inner container will completely fill up the parent container, minus 100px on the top and bottom and 50px on the right and left. The vertical margin works as expected, but the horizontal margin actually extends out of the parent div, so that the inner container still appears to be taking up the entire width of the parent div.

I'm not sure if this is related to flexbox or not.

Here is an isolated CodePen https://codepen.io/MaxMillington2/pen/EQWZoj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `align-items: center` with `column` direction, the item will collapse to its content width, instead of with its default, `stretch`, which makes it fill its parent's width.

Additionally, when setting `width: 100%` to the `inner`, it will override the default `stretch`, which will make the item be 100% of parent's width + margin.

For the expected output, remove `align-items: center` on the `outer` and `width: 100%` on `inner`.

Stack snippet

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f4f6f8;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 100px 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  outer
  <div class='inner'>
    inner
  </div>
</div>
```